# Mac doesn't sleep when lid is closed, but upon opening the lid it falls asleep?

Tags: sleep-wake

When I close the lid, my macbook pro does not go to sleep. However, when I open the lid, it will go to sleep. How do I correct this problem?

Comment: does this behavior persist through a restart?

Comment: "When I close the lid, my macbook pro does not go to sleep." How do you know?

Comment: Are you certain it doesn't go to sleep? It can take some time (max of 30 seconds I think) and the little light should blink (and screen of ofcourse). Also the fans stop spinning

Comment: How long have you waited?   I have a 2011 MacBook Pro (non retina) with 16 GB of RAM.  When you put the computer to sleep, the contents are RAM are written to disk so that should the battery die while it is asleep, you are able to "wake" the mac back up when it has power again.  That can take some time, especially if I have a number of programs open.  Before I put an SSD in here, it could take as long a eight minutes!

Comment: Does this happen everywhere you use the notebook?  Do you have any kind of magnetic bracelet?

Answer (score 1):

The SMC controls things like sleep, fans, etc.  Reset the SMC by following the instructions here:  http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

EDIT: In case that link dies, you restart the MacBook Pro while holding down these keys on the left side of the keyboard: Ctrl + Option + Shift